# What are some statistical distributions with the irrational numbers e and pi in their functions? (apart from the most common - Normal, Poisson)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-function, pi

I've been researching on the application and origin of irrational numbers in probability theory and statistical distributions, so far having derived a unique proof of Stirling's approximation, and establishing a graphical link between binomial and normal distributions. I'd like to explore some more distributions with e and pi in their functions, so as to mathematically explain their origin and hopefully understand their importance in the calculation of probability. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some that come to mind:

$e:$ Exponential, Gamma, Beta, hyperbolic, log-normal, weibull, Laplace

$\sqrt{\pi}:$ Chi-square with 1df, t distribution, log-normal

You may find this list useful:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions

For distributions defined using the Gamma function, you may be interested to know $\Gamma(n+0.5) \propto \sqrt{\pi}$ for any natural number $n$. So such distributions can depend on $\pi$ for certain parameters.